# vscode ctrl+p show matched string: shows files but not able to see matched strings when file paths are long

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

In vs code i am trying to search for files using : eg `ctrl+p` and search `django contrib auth`

[image]

It does not show the search terms it focuses main on the files

where as in sublime text: i can see the matched strings also

[image]

this is important for me, because i want to see the where the terms are matching

How to get this feature in vscode

Comment: What's keeping you from just using Sublime?

Comment: this quick find feature.